# MySQL Trigger UPDATE date doesn't work when old value is NULL

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to update a Timestamp field to NOW() when the value isn't provided by the user.

So i wrote this trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_SAS_MASTERDATA_TO_IPS_SI_UPDATE_DATE 
BEFORE UPDATE ON SAS_MASTERDATA_TO_IPS_SI 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF !(NEW.UPDATE_DATE <=> NULL) THEN 
            SET NEW.UPDATE_DATE= NOW(); 
        END IF; 
    END
```

It works well, excepted when the old value of the Timestamp is NULL. In this case, it stays to NULL.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it seems like you are checking if the date is null, and if it's not, the date is updated. You never state that you want to do anything when the value is null, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's technically no such thing as not providing a value in an update, because when no value is provided, that's exactly the same as providing the current/existing value.

`NEW.UPDATE_DATE <=> OLD.UPDATE_DATE` will evaluate to true in both of those conditions (providing no value vs. providing the existing value).  They are undistinguishable, in a trigger.

MySQL's built in functionality for timestamps implements what you are looking for, without a trigger, if you declare the column like this, in the table definition.

```
UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

If the column value is not provided in the update query, but at least one other column is changed by the update, the timestamp column will be set to `NOW()`.